# update table with data from other table if not null?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Basically what I want to do is copy the value of a column from one table to another column in another table.

The query I am using is:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET product_code = 
(SELECT `value` FROM t2 WHERE t2.variant_id = t1.variant_id AND key_id = 10);
```

Which is working fine, but there is a mismatch in columns,

so I need to add in a clause which will only do the update on that row, if the subquery does not return null.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just being doing the update across a join like this

```
UPDATE
t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.variant_id = t2.variant_id
SET t1.product_code = t2.value
WHERE t2.key_id = 10
AND t2.value IS NOT NULL
```

There is no need to worry about nulls in that case as the inner join will only select rows where the variant_id exists in both tables.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question: what if`'value` column has a null even though a join occurs?

Comment: @Bohemian You are correct in that as it was initially written, if `t2.value` equals `null` it would still make an update.  I originally read the OP as wanting to only make sure there were matching records between the tables, not just eliminate the cases where `value` is `null`.  That is a very simple addition the `WHERE` clause that I have now made. My main intent was to indicate that doing the update across a join is typically going to be more efficient that using a subselect assuming the columns used in the join and filter are indexed.

Answer (score 5):

Use the old value if the query returns `null`:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET product_code = 
ifnull(
    (SELECT `value` FROM t2 WHERE t2.variant_id = t1.variant_id AND key_id = 10), 
    product_code);
```

FYI, in mysql using the old value doesn't count as an "update" in any way (either the number of rows affected or the logged changes)

Comment: I actually ended up doing exactly this, as I kept doing research after I asked, but I accepted the answer below as I always prefer joins over sub-queries.