# SQL UPDATE ... SELECT, or leave as is if not found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that maps Users to Zones according to their location, and the zone boundaries:

```sql
UPDATE User u SET u.zoneId = (
   SELECT z.id FROM Zone z
   WHERE ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
   ORDER BY z.level DESC
   LIMIT 1
);
```

This works fine, although it tries to set `zoneId` to `NULL` when no matching Zone is found.

In my domain, a User must always have a Zone, therefore `zoneId` is `NOT NULL`. This requirement is enforced when the User is created, but could potentially be broken when the Zone boundaries are redrawn, and the above query is run.

How can I make this SQL query **update `zoneId` when a match is found, and keep the current value when no match is found?**

Comment: I saw a question that kind of has the same problem, they solved it by joining the two tables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634133/update-table-with-data-from-other-table-if-not-null

Comment: @Tim I don't think I can replace the subquery with a JOIN, as I'm performing an ORDER BY as well (several Zones can match, only the highest level (smallest sub-zone) is returned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
UPDATE User u
    SET u.zoneId = coalesce((SELECT z.id
                             FROM Zone z
                             WHERE ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
                             ORDER BY z.level DESC
                             LIMIT 1
                            ), u.zoneId);
```